# How to hide circular compass icon on MKMapview in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to hide the circular compass icon on `MKMapview` which appears when a user rotates the map. I have attached a screen shot for reference. I don't want to display the circular compass icon but I do want to allow rotation on the map.

[image: MapView]

Comment: if i set myMapViewObject.rotateEnabled = NO; then this icon not appear, but i dont want to disable rotation.

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19196725/790842. And for your layout I have a suggestion, to move the SearchBar to the Navigationbar, so it won't be blocked by compass.

Comment: Are you adding the "Search for Oulet" ("Ou**t**let"?) view to the MKMapView directly?  That would explain why the compass appears on top.  Like iphonic says, the search view should be added as a subview of the parent vc view, not the map view.  Don't modify the map's internal view hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

Starting in iOS 9 you can finally hide the compass in `MKMapView`.

```
mapView.showsCompass = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not rotating the map programatically and it hasn't already been rotated, disable rotation entirely, using

mapView.rotateEnabled = NO;
The compass only shows up when the map is rotated, so by doing this you ensure that the compass is never triggered.

Comment: Thanks,but i already mentioned i don't want to restrict from rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The current iOS maps does not have the option to turn off the compass.
MapKit Class in the apple documentation also does not carry any information about a compass setting as either a property or creation only setting.

Without restriction on rotation you need to try with the solution given at following url:

http://jdkuzma.tumblr.com/post/79294999487/xcode-mapview-offsetting-the-compass-and-legal

Comment: Please consider putting in essential parts of the answers here. Link only answers can go dead over a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try it by setting its layout margin:

By moving a little bit lower:

```
[self.mapView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 20, 0)];
```

or moving it up a little bit higher:

```
[self.mapView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-50, 0, -50, 0)];
```

Hope this might get you what you need.